# postgresql, how do I connect to it using pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql

I did the following:

```
sudo juju bootstrap

juju deploy postgresql

juju expose postgresql

juju status
```

environment: local

machines:

"0":

```
agent-state: started
agent-version: 1.16.5.1
dns-name: 10.0.3.1
instance-id: localhost
series: precise


 "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.16.5.1
    instance-id: ariskk-local-machine-1
    instance-state: missing
    series: precise
services:
  postgresql:
    charm: cs:precise/postgresql-59
    exposed: true
    relations:
      replication:
      - postgresql
    units:
      postgresql/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.16.5.1
        machine: "1"
        open-ports:
        - 5432/tcp
        public-address: 10.0.3.148
```

How do I connect to this instance (set password?)

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, this is 1 way I found:
(deploying to my local cloud)

sudo juju bootstrap

juju deploy postgresql pg-a

juju expose postgresql pg-a

juju status

## add local IP to the allowed hosts

juju set pg-a admin_addresses=10.0.3.1

## login to the box to change postgres pwd

ssh ubuntu@10.0.3.131

sudo -u postgres psql

\password postgres